# C++ - rearange vector of instances by class type given by a pattern

Tags: c++11, c++14

I have vector of instances, something like

```
class A;
class B : public A;
class C : public A;
class D : public A;

A * a1  = new A;
A * a2  = new A;
A * b1  = new B;
A * b2  = new B;
A * c   = new C;
A * d   = new D;

std::vector<A *> data = {a1, b1, b2, c, a2, d};
```

Is is possible to rearange array so that the order of class types is given by a pattern? Somethng like:

```
pattern1: A, B, C, D
result1: {a1, a2, b1, b2, c, d}

pattern2: A, D, B, C
result2: {a1, a2, d, b1, b2, c}
```

The pattern is just a pattern, so it tels us, that A is before B etc. Is this solvable (C++11 or C++14) without the need of modifying existing classes?

Comment: We can't respond if we don't know how are made existing classes

Comment: @max66 I dont always have source of classes available, so I cannot modify them. Based on that, I am loking for solution not based on classes implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::type_index` to define the order and then just (`stable_`)`sort` on that.

```
struct A { virtual ~A() = default; }; // you need virtual method for typeid operator to look at dynamic type.
struct B : A {};
struct C : A {};
struct D : A {};

A * a1  = new A;
A * a2  = new A;
A * b1  = new B;
A * b2  = new B;
A * c   = new C;
A * d   = new D;

template<typename T>
void rearrange(T begin, T end)
{
    std::vector<std::type_index> order = { std::type_index(typeid(*a1)), std::type_index(typeid(*b1)), std::type_index(typeid(*c)), std::type_index(typeid(*d)) };

    std::stable_sort(begin, end, [&](const A* lhs, const A* rhs)
    {
        return std::find(order.begin(), order.end(), std::type_index(typeid(*lhs))) < std::find(order.begin(), order.end(), std::type_index(typeid(*rhs)));
    });
}
```

See it live on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d749bfcbe77e8cf2).

Answer (score 0):

- You can use some logic(#include "typeinfo") wchich will check type of object and rearrange elements, depending to your patterns.

if (typeid(a) == typeid(b)) {

cout << "same type here \n";

}

string s = typeid(someClassInst).name();